# Using Redis as a session store in Node js and how to get values from it?

Tags: node.js, session, express, redis

I used Redis to store session in my nodejs server. This is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var connect = require("connect");
var path = require('path');
var RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(express);

var redis = require("redis").createClient();

var app = express();

app.set('port', 8888);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.cookieParser());


app.use(express.session({secret: 'blues',
    cookie: { secure: true },
    store: new RedisStore({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
        client: redis })
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('/login', function(req,res){
    res.render('login.html', {title: 'Login'});
});

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

When I run the server, and access the url `http://localhost:8888/login`, then come back to check the Redis server, I found 3 sessions saved there, like this

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "sess:DGtMAO3pRPExzPjFS_B07bXP"
2) "sess:bzPTRrlXXe1DhzNze0JdZswt"
3) "sess:-RM8kkNtJ0jj3nhuYmiuw0f6"
```

What does it mean? Why 3 sessions (I had double-check with FLUSHDB command)?

EDIT: Ok I have some test and it turns out the other two sessions is from a css and a js file in login.html. But there are something I don't understand that when I press F5, 3 new session is stored in Redis. Why is that? Didn't session stay the same until it expire?

Another problem is, with above code how can I retrieve the session saved in Redis? I used this:

```
redis.get('"sess:' + req.session.id + '"', function(err, result){
    console.log("Get session: " + util.inspect(result,{ showHidden: true, depth: null }));
    });
```

it return null, although I can retrieve it with the same req.session.id in Redis server.
Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, the mistake here is I have to save the session first then I can get it from Redis

Comment: can you eloborate the mistake? Provide some code?